# Solving $y’=(y^2-c^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$$y’(x)=(y^2(x)-c^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Using seperation method gives me really weird integals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y’ = \sqrt{y^2-c^2}$$ $$\implies \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-c^2}}\, dy = \int 1\, dx$$ $$\implies \cosh^{-1}(\frac{y}{c}) = x + k \equiv \implies y = c\cosh(x+k)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici its not, sorry.

Comment: oh I got some integral with logaritm in modulus. You know where I can find info on this hyperbolic functions?

Comment: I got $ln(y+ (y^2-c^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})$ on the left.

Comment: @l33tg33k  This is just a more compact way of expressing the same. See here: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/functions_and_graphs/hyperbolic_functions/inverses.html

Comment: @l33tg33k (+1) to you for getting a right answer. Next time, show your attempts in the question itself.

Comment: dont we need $\frac{y(x)}{c}≥1$ for all $x$ for the inverse cosh to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: substitute $y=c\sec \theta$